# how do I fill a shape with other small objects and text in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

This is what I need to design. Is there an automatic way or just manual?
thx

Comment: What do you mean when you're saying "an automatic way". Do you want to create it or fill with colour only?

Comment: I'd wager there's a 90% chance this was done with Adobe Illustrator or some other vector-based application and not Photoshop.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean. Please edit your question and explain in a little more detail what it is that you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

They most likely made this in Illustrator. The person who made this manually placed objects to form the design. You could find a decorate flower set and make your own. There is an option in Illustrator for (object - envelope distort - make with top object) which forms an object inside another object. [See example](http://www.printplace.com/tutorials/warping-text-to-fit-into-shapes-with-illustrator.aspx). You would only need to make half and then do a reversal of that side.

Just to reiterate, there is no automated way to create something like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this depends on whether you want a raster or a vector version of this graphic.

Manually tracing this would take forever in Photoshop; it would be considerably faster in Illustrator, and you could tweak the paths with much greater control, but would still depend on you spending some time tracing.

In terms of automatic methods, I have never placed much trust in Illustrator's auto-tracing tools - the results, in my opinion, are invariably messy and inaccurate (unless you are auto-tracing a high resolution graphic). Photoshop doesn't really have an auto-trace option, specially not for scalable vectors.

If you can spare the time, I would recommend a manual vector trace in Illustrator; failing that, or if you're really up against it in terms of deadlines, I would just buy it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with custom Warp in Transform (CTR + T) Command to give itany shape to your design wether it is vector or raster.
Watch [this Video Tutoria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SxrqgLFbzL8)l to do this:

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit how you'd do that? I don't really see how you'd achieve the OP's desired effect with just Warp.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a job for a vector graphics program like Illustrator, not Photoshop. When I first read the title of your question I thought you wanted a repeating pattern. This isn't repeating, it's just left/right mirrored.
The reason I think this is done in illustrator is that Illustrator allows you to draw any curve-based shapes, which in Photoshop is a lot more difficult.

When you check the image with Shutterstock you'll notice it is available as vector image.